# Python | Convert a JSON dictionary with a list with dictionary entries into a DataFrame (pandas)

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have imported a JSON file with 10000 rows and saved it in the variable data.
I want a table that shows the name of the father, the mother, the living situation and the number of pets.
For this, I wanted to use a DataFrame from pandas (python). Unfortunately, I don't know how to extract the data. I always get a Family column with {...} entries.

`df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['Family'])
```

Comment: Also add some explanation of the code, see how do I write a good answer [answer].